# How to properly overload postfix increment operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, compiler-warnings, postfix-operator

Is there a way to modify this code so that I do not receive a warning when compiling ? Also, couldn't this code potentially result in a segfault since the memory it is going to access to retrieve the value of x in main got deallocated at the end of the operator function call?

```
class A {

  int x; /* value to be post-incremented */

  public:

  A() {  /* default constructor */
  }

  A( A & toCopy ) {   /* copy constructor */
    x = toCopy.x;
  }

  A & operator++(int) {  /* returns a reference to A */

    A copy( *this );         /* allocate a copy on the stack */
    ++x;

    return copy;            /* PROBLEM: returning copy results in a warning */

  }                         /* memory for copy gets deallocated */

}; /* end of class A */

int main() {

  A object;
  object.x = 5;

  cout << (object++).x << endl;   /* Possible segfault ? */

}
```

Comment: Simply don't return by reference. Return by value, making another copy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to return a value (not a reference):

```
A operator++(int) { /*...*/ }
```

this will resolve the compiler warning and you won't end up with a dangling reference.

Comment: Omg it was that easy.  Thanks.
I'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Can you explain one thing? What is the value of copy ? Like what exactly am I returning that makes ( object++ ).x possible ?

Comment: @KacyRaye You are returning a copy of the value as it was before you modified it. The orignal object is modified (`object` in your example). This returned value is called a temporary (of type `A`) and hence you can access the temporary's members by adding `.x`.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but I'll be more specific.  The value of a pointer is a memory address. The value of an int is a number.  But what exactly is the value I'm returning ? Is it the memory address to the block of memory I allocated for copy ?

Comment: @KacyRaye It's a bit more complicated, probably too much for the comments. Short form: The caller provides the memory for the return value of a function which is passed (as a pointer) to the called function (here: the operator). The called function is responsible for constructing the object (aka the temporary) in the return slot. The caller is (later) required to destroy the temporary (call dtor if necessary, free memory). HTH

Comment: That makes 100% sense. Do you mind explaining what the "short form" process was when I was returning by reference ?

Comment: @KacyRaye Short form: The called function creates `A copy` and returns a reference to it (internally a pointer) to the caller. While returning (leaving the operator's function scope) it also destroys its local variable (`copy`) and hence the reference becomes a dangling reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That made perfect sense. I always like when people can give an explanation of what's happening in memory.  That really helped my understanding. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The postfix operator doesn't return by reference, returns by value:

```
A operator++(int) {  /* returns a copy */

    A copy( *this );         /* allocate a copy on the stack */
    ++x;

    return copy;

  }
```

Note that in your code you are returning **a reference to a local variable, which has undefined-behavior**.

Also note that the return copy could be easilly elided by the compiler through a [NRVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) (That code its pretty *NRVO-friendly*).